# List(Of T) overload issue in DataGridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm using `List(Of T)` to contains my database field (invoice_id and item_id) and want to display it in `DataGridView`. First, I declare each of them as a class and then add them to my list then display it in `DataGridView` but when I compile it, the program is not responding.

My guess is that my database source is too large, because when I change the source (database field), it worked nicely. So how do I solve this `List(Of T)` capacity issues?

This is my code:

```
Sub view()

    Dim msql2 As String
    msql2 = "select invoice_id, item_id from detail"
    Dim arayD As New List(Of INVOICE)

    CMD2 = New MySqlCommand(msql2, conn.konek)

    Try

        Dim res = CMD2.ExecuteReader()
        Dim INVO As INVOICE = Nothing
        While res.Read()
            INVO = New INVOICE
            With INVO
                .invoice_id = hasil2.GetString("invoice_id")
                .item_id = hasil2.GetString("item_id")
            End With
            arayD.Add(INVO)

        End While
        dgv.DataSource = arayD
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR")

    End Try
End Sub

Public Class INVOICE
    Private _kodeF As Integer
    Public Property invoice_id() As Integer
        Get
            Return _kodeF
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _kodeF = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _kodeBrg As String
    Public Property item_id() As String
        Get
            Return _kodeBrg
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _kodeBrg = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: It certainly isn't a problem with `List`, that can handle a huge number of items. The most likely problem is with the data grid. How many items are you displaying? Do you actually need to display all of them? Displaying more than ~100 items at once usually doesn't make any sense, no user is going to go though such a big list.

Comment: my case is that i want to fetch two field from by db into two dynamic dimensional array then compare it with one dynamic dimensional array to create a new two dynamic dimensional array from it

between array, arraylist and list of, i chose list of(t) because it can contain a huge data..

Comment: How many records are you pulling back?  If it's a huge list, as @svick mentioned, it could be that your program is running fine, but since the data retrieval is running on the UI thread it's blocking and making the program unresponsive.  Try moving your data retrieval and manipulation to a background thread.

Comment: Have you look into the [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)? I really think you should examine this class in reflector. It might at least give you some inspiration.

Comment: The `GetRange` method of List(Of) should be able to allow you to test your code with a reduced list of data and see if it is indeed a thread issue.  If so a global index variable and a couple of buttons will allow the user to flip between record sets.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a fast solution then add the following line inside your `While Loop` :

```
While res.Read()
    Application.DoEvents()
    ...
End While
```

Or use a BackgroundWorker as the following:

```
Private WithEvents bgWorker As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
Private arayD As New List(Of INVOICE)

Sub view()
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub bgWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.DoWork
    Dim dReader As DataReader

    Using YourConnection 
        Using YourCommand 
            YourConnection.Open()
            dReader = YourCommand.ExecuteReader()
            If dReader.HasRows Then
                While dReader.Read
                    arayD.Add(New INVOICE With {
                                                .invoice_id = hasil2.GetString("invoice_id"),
                                                .item_id = hasil2.GetString("item_id")
                                               }
                             )
                End While
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    MsgBox("Ready to go")
    dgv.DataSource = arayD
End Sub
```

Also you can get the count of the result and use it with a progressbar.